# Creating Script to fill out javascript form

Tags: javascript, html, cmd

Objective: Write a one click script to change IP address of a device through its Javascript form.

Hi! I am trying to write a script to fill out a form on a Javascript. I need to change three values on it. I have access to the code but cannot change it.

Using the GUI you would simply change the values in the textboxes and click the OK button.

**format of variables:**
*document.adminForm.gprIP.value*

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you planning to run this Javascript? In the browser console?

Comment: you can add javascript as bookmark (may google "js harlem shake")

Comment: Yeah in the browser is fine.

Comment: The bookmark answer would work well! Can you please elaborate on how to do that? I haven't done javascript in 10 years

Answer (score 0):

This problem was solved by sloppily using a keylogger script.